# Proof regarding unitary self-adjoin linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm suck on how to do the following Linear Algebra proof:

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$.

Prove that for all $x \in V$, $||T(x)\pm ix||^2=||T(x)||^2+||x||^2.$

Deduce that $T-iI$ is invertible and that $[(T-iI)^{-1}]^{*}=(T+iI)^{-1}.$

Furthermore, show that $(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}$ is unitary.

---

My attempt at a solution (to the first part):

$||T(x)\pm ix||^2=\left< T(x)\pm ix, T(x)\pm ix\right>$

$=\left< T(x), T(x) \pm ix\right>\pm \left<ix,  T(x)\pm ix \right>$

...

$=\left<T(x), T(x) \right>+ \left<x,x \right>$

$=||T(x)||^2+||x||^2$

The ... is the part I'm stuck on (I know, it's the bulk of the first part).
I have yet to consider the next parts since I'm still stuck on this one.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use linearity again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$(Tx+ix,Tx+ix)=(Tx,Tx)+(ix, Tx)+(Tx, ix)+(ix,ix)=|Tx|^{2}+i(x,Tx)-i(x,Tx)+|x|^{2}$$where I assume you define the inner product to be Hermitian. I think for $Tx-ix$ it should be similar. The rest should be leave as an exercise for you; they are not that difficult.

To solve the last one, notice we have $(T-iI)^{-1}$'s adjoint to be $(T+iI)^{-1}$, and $(T+iI)$'a adjoint to be $T-iI$. The first one can be proved by expanding $(T-iI)^{-1}$ as $(I-iT^{-1})^{-1}T^{-1}$, then use geometric series.

The second one follows by $(Tx+ix,y)=(Tx,y)+(x,-iy)=(x,Ty)+(x-iy)=(x,(T-I)y)$.

If we want $(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}$ to be unitary, then we want 
$$((T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}x,(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}x)=(x,x)$$ for all $x$. Moving around this is the same as 
$$((T^{2}+I)(T-iI)^{-1}x,(T-iI)^{-1}x)=(x,x)$$ but this is the same as 
$$((T+iI)x, (T-iI)^{-1}x)=(x,x)$$
and the result follows because we know $(T-iI)^{*}=(T+iI)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you! To show that $T-iI$ is invertible, we want to show that there's some matrix $A$ such that $A(T-iI)=(T-iI)=I$. Since $T$ is self-adjoint we know $T=T^{*}$, and I can plug this in, but then I'm stuck again. Any suggestions for the last two parts?

Comment: To show $T-iI$ is invertible, just assume there is some $x$ such that $(T-iI)x=0$. See why this is impossible. You should try yourself for the rest.

Comment: Okay so if there's some $x$ such that $(T-iI)x=0$ then we have $T(x)-iI(x)=0$ which means $T(x)=iI(x)$. Can this not hold true since $iI(x)$ is not self-adjoint, or something like that? Then that means that the kernel of $(T-iI)=\{0\}$ which means it must be invertible?

Comment: @user78026: Observe that if $(T-iI)x=0$, then $(Tx-ix, Tx-ix)=0$. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah! No, it's not possible, since that would mean that $Tx-ix$ is orthogonal to itself. Awesome. Thank you! ---- I was able to figure out the next part ($[(T-iI)^{-1}]^{*}=(T+il)^{-1}$), but am still suck on the last part (showing that $(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}$ is unitary).  (I'll post what I've done so far in the next comment).

Comment: I'm using the definition of unitary so I want to show that $||(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}(x)||=||x||$. So far I have $||(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}(x)||=\left<(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}(x), (T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}(x) \right>=\left<(T+iI)(x), (T+iI)(x) \right>+\left<(T-iI)^{-1}(x), (T+iI)(x) \right>++\left<(T+iI)(x), (T-iI)^{-1}(x)\right>+\left<(T-iI)^{-1}(x), (T-iI)^{-1}(x) \right> $ I'm assuming that we need to use the fact that $[(T-iI)^{-1}]^{*}=(T+il)^{-1}$, or maybe $||T(x)\pm ix||^2=||T(x)||^2+||x||^2$ but I'm stuck here. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the definition $$UU^{*}=U^{*}U=1$$ Then you need to show $(T+iI)^{*}=T-iI$. But this is just definition. Then you have $(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}$'s adjoint to be $(T+iI)^{-1}(T-iI)$. However this does not seem to cancel out nicely.

Comment: Perhaps I'm starting in the wrong direction? Would it be easier to show statement equivalent to $||T(x)||=||x||$ instead?

Comment: updated. Hopefully this is a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I checked the problem and it is, in fact, show that $(T+iI)(T-iI)^{-1}$ is unitary. I'm thinking the proof should be similar, though.

Comment: I see. I think now it is proved. Sorry I took it to be easier than it is.

Comment: No worries! I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is should be a correct sketch of the proof...I will leave the details to you

1). $||T(x) \pm ix||^2 = <T(x) \pm ix,T(x) \pm ix>$ 
by definition

2).$<T(x) \pm ix,T(x) \pm ix> = <T(x), T(x) > + <ix, ix> \pm <T(x), ix> \pm <ix, T(x)>$

3). But.. we know that $<T(x) , ix> = -<ix,T(x)> $ since $T = T^*$  and $ix = (-ix)^*$ which means the last two terms of the RHS of step two cancel each other out leaving you with the result. $<T(x), T(x)> + <ix, ix> = ||T(x)||^2 + ||x||^2$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the sketch! I was able to work out the first part with your help.

Comment: To show that $T-iI$ is invertible, we want to show that there's some matrix $A$ such that $A(T-iI)=(T-iI)=I$. Since $T$ is self-adjoint we know $T=T^{*}$, and I can plug this in, but then I'm stuck again. Any suggestions for the last two parts?

Comment: I would start with rewriting the correct definition of invertible matrix: $A A(^-1) = A(^-1) A = I$?

Comment: (yeah, that's what I meant, I just forgot the second A, sorry!)